# Setting ItemSource for ListView crashes on iOS, works fine in Android

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an App using Xamarin Forms where the `HomePage` has a `ListView` inside of the main `StackLayout`.  Grouping is enabled in my list and it is declared in my XAML as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="listsListView" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding groupName}"  
        HasUnevenRows="True" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}">
  <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
              <Label Text="{Binding groupName}"/>
          </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
              <Label Text="{Binding itemName}"/>
          </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In my code behind I set the contents of my `ListView`:

```
//ListGroup extends List<Item> and gives the name for the group header
group1 = new ListGroup("Group 1");
group2 = new ListGroup("Group 2");
//I then add a few items to my ListGroups

groupedLists = new List<ListGroup>();

groupedLists.Add(childListGroup); 
groupedLists.Add(listsListGroup); 

listsListView.ItemsSource = groupedLists;
```

Here is my implementation of `ListGroup`:

```
public class ListGroup : List<Item>
{
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public ListGroup(string Name)
    {
        this.groupName = Name;
        ShortName = "";
    }
}
```

I went through my code debugging and the error happens at the last line when setting the `ItemSource` of my `ListView`.  The odd thing is everything works perfectly in Android.  However, in iOS, I get: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'"

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error on iOS?  I've been doing Android for a while but am very new to iOS.

```
Date/Time:       2017-03-23T01:58:34Z
Launch Time:     2017-03-23T01:55:34Z
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.2 (16D32)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x11a944dd6
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000118af9d33 0x118a03000 + 1010995
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000119a4421e 0x119a3f000 + 21022
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000118b632b5 0x118a03000 + 1442485
3   Foundation                           0x00000001105a2624 0x11058c000 + 91684
4   MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcd29a0 0x10d9f1000 + 3021216
5   MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcdc73a 0x10d9f1000 + 3061562
6   MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcd568a 0x10d9f1000 + 3032714
7   MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcdbdbd 0x10d9f1000 + 3059133
8   MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcdd171 0x10d9f1000 + 3064177
9   UIKit                                0x000000010eacff71 0x10e96e000 + 1449841
10  MyApp.iOS                         0x000000010dcdd2f9 0x10d9f1000 + 3064569
11  ???                                  0x00000001321d76ae 0x0 + 0
```

Comment: Can you also share how you implemented `ListGroup`?

Comment: Yes I'll edit it in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but when I removed the `GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"` line from my XAML it now works.  I think I had been following a tutorial and left it in my code on accident.